# Fetch Email Address for SentOnBehalfOfName in outlook 2007 VSTO code

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I am developing Outlook 2007 VSTO addin. I need to fetch the email address specified in from section like given below:

info@xyz.com; on behalf of; KANxyz SAXYZ **[saxyz7@gmail.com]**
[image]

I need to fetch **[saxyz7@gmail.com]** in code. But I just get **SentOnBehalfOfName** property that only returns the name (in this case "KANxyz SAXYZ").

```
        try
        {

            Outlook.Selection objSelection = null;
            // Get the Application object
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

            try
            {
                var window = application.ActiveWindow();
                try
                {
                    objSelection = application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    //Ignore; NULL check below will branch out 
                }
                objMail = default(Outlook.MailItem);

                try
                {
                    objMail = objSelection[1];
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                if ((objMail != null) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(objMail.SenderEmailAddress))
                {
                    email = objMail.SenderEmailAddress;
                    emailFrom = objMail.SentOnBehalfOfName;
                }
            }
            catch { }

            if ((objMail == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(objMail.SenderEmailAddress))
            {
                // Get the active Inspector object and check if is type of MailItem
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();
                if (inspector != null)
                {
                    mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
                    if (mailItem != null)
                    {
                        email = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
                        emailFrom = objMail.SentOnBehalfOfName;
                    }       
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){ }
```

Comment: Doesn't SenderEmailAddress give you the email address you need?

Comment: SenderEmailAddress  gives me the email id of sender but there some text methioning that email is sent on behalf of another user also it specifies the email id of that user, that I want to fetch.

Comment: you can check my screenshot. The From : shows 2 email ids. info@xyz.com on behalf of KANxyz SAXYZ [saxyz7@gmail.com]

Comment: @EricLegault i want saxyz7@gmail.com but i only get info@xyz.com and the name : KANxyz SAXYZ